# How to populate a datagrid based on value in combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am facing a question (maybe very basic).
I have a combobox1 and it has filled values (say 1,2,3,4,5) from earlier controls.

Now based on choosing a value from the combobox1, I want to populate the columns of a datagrid.

Now, the datagrid has 4 columns, 
one DataGridcheckboxcolumn(value set to checked as default), 
one DataGridtextboxcolumn1 for autopopulation from the combobox1(the most important part), one DataGridTextBoxColumn2(to set as default value) and 
one DataGridComboBoxColumn(set to default value AVS_DB frm AVS,DB,AVS_DB).

My question is very basic.

How do I get the values in the datagrid populated.

The xaml and the codebehind are as follows:

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgQCNumbers" Width="400" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="100" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Row="6" 
          SelectionChanged="dtgQCNumbers_SelectionChanged" 
          Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,10,125,15">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Enter_Choice" Width="100" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=DataGridCheckBox_Option}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="QC_ID" Width="100" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=DataGridTextBox_QCList1}" />                               
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Summary" Width="100"
            Binding="{Binding Path=DataGridTextBox_QCSummary}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ControlOption" Width="100"
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=DataGridComboxBox_Control}">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                <col:ArrayList>
                    <sys:String>AVS</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>DB</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>AVS_DB</sys:String>
                </col:ArrayList>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
            grid.ColumnWidth = new DataGridLength(100);
        </DataGrid>
```

*The code to populate the ComboBox (before the datagrid) is:*

```
private void ddlCR_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     btnSubmit.IsEnabled = true;
     ClearStatusMessages();
     if (ddlCR.SelectedIndex > 0)
     {
        PopulateQCIdList();
     }
  }
```

Now the PopulateQCIdList() should populate the DataGrid Columns (all 4 Columns, 3 default values and value driven from what we choose from the combobox)

The codebehind is what I want to know to populate data after the ComboBox has been populated, i.e. I want to know how exactly to fill the DataGrid using the PopulateQCIdList() method.

Please edit/let me know if I missed any information

Comment: What about binding the currently selected row to your controls ? Like in a master / detail view ?

Comment: Vincent, could you point me any example?

Comment: I think I can bind a datatable to a the datagrid; in doing so, I can map all columns of the datatable to the corresponding columns in the datagrid. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you did. But you have two options :
Option 1 : Define a Class that will hold your Data, with meaningfull property names, for your boolean, string, string, enum values. This class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Then bind your DataGrid to a List of those objects.
Option 2 : Define a database, (i use SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5, you can use Access, MySQL, ... there are many DB), then bind the DataGrid to this DB.